# In Grunt, how can I set package.json version to a specific version using Grunt plugins?

Tags: npm, gruntjs, gruntfile

**UPDATE**:
The grunt-bump plugin only works for versions that meet the semantic versioning format. If I use a version, e.g., `test-2.0.0` that doesn't meet semver, it doesn't work.

grunt-cli v1.4.2

Using a `Gruntfile.js`, how can I set my `package.json` to a specific version string that's not necessarily a semver version? I use the [grunt-bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bump) plugin, so I do this

```
Gruntfile.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    bump: {
      options: {
        files: ['package.json', 'package-lock.json'],
        updateConfigs: ['pkg'],
        versionType: 'patch',
        ...
      },
      ...
  });
  ...

  var myTasks = [
    "task1",
    "clean",
    ....
    "compress"
  ];

  grunt.registerTask('build', 'Build version', function () {
      grunt.config('bump.options.setVersion', "tag-2.0.0");
      grunt.task.run(myTasks);
  });
};
```

...then do this on the command line...

```
$ npm grunt build
```

However, `package.json` is not updated to `"version": "tag-2.0.0"`. What am I missing?

In Gulp I use the `gulp-pipe` to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I marked this as the answer, but it's a wrong answer. This replaces ALL the occurrences of the `x.y.z` version in the `package*.json` files, NOT just the `version` key.

I ended up using the [grunt-text-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace) plugin.

I now have this.

```
Gruntfile.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  gruntfile.initConfig ({
    replace: {
      pkg_versions: {
        src: ['./package*.json'],
        overwrite: true,  // overwrite matched source files in dist
        replacements: [{
          from: '<%= pkg.version %>', 
          to: '2.0.0'
        }]
      }
    }
  });
  ...
  var myTasks = [
    "task1",
    "clean",
    "replaceZ:pkg_version",
    ....
    "compress"
  ];
  ...
  grunt.registerTask('build', 'Build version', function () {
      grunt.task.run(myTasks);
  });
};
```